# Что делает InkCollectorStrokeEventHandler?

Tags: c#

Что делает `InkCollectorStrokeEventHandler` и для чего можно его применять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел: Представляет метод, который обрабатывает событие `Stroke` в `InkCollector`